# Parsing retrieved localStorage item brings undesired result in console

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I am making a note web app using localStorage, when user submits a note, the values from the input and textarea are saved in a object.

Each note created is a object containing key/value pairs

- id: 0
- title: value from input
- content: value from textarea

After localStorage contains least one item with a string from then on in when a new note is created, I get/retrieve the localStorage string which will contain past entered notes in string format.

1. Parse the localStorage string and save it into a variable/array to have the prior notes to add on to.
2. Push new input values saved into input object each time, to the array before setting the localStorage item with the array(stringifying it of course).

Below is the function that's responsible for saving the note into localStorage

```
    // User clicks to save note
    post_note_button.onclick = function() {

    // Get values from input and textarea
    var note_title = document.getElementById("note-title").value;
    var note_textarea = document.getElementById("note-textarea").value;

    // Each time note is created, new values from input will be saved
    var input = { id: note_id_count, title: note_title, content: note_textarea };

    // ------------------------------------------------

    switch(localStorage.getItem("note")) {

        // If retrieve for localStorage item returns false/doesn't exist
        // PURPOSE: Set localStorage string for first time
        // 1. Create localStorage item with values from user's input
        case null:
            localStorage.setItem("note", JSON.stringify(input));
        break;

        // If retrieve for localStorage item returns true/exists
        // PURPOSE: To retrieve localStorage string and manipulate it
        // 1. Changing localStorage string, requires string to be retrieved and saved as array
        // 2. Add item to array
        // 3. Create/set localStorage item with values from array, convert to string
        default:
            var note_array = [JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("note"))];
            console.log(note_array);

            note_array.push(input);

            localStorage.setItem("note", JSON.stringify(note_array));
        break;
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------ 
};
```

**MY PROBLEM:**
When I **console.log & parse** the localStorage item "note" after adding a few notes, I should get

```
Array [ Object, Object, Object ]
```

instead I get:

```
Array [ Array[2], Object ]
```

codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdjMYq

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code ... external links might be nonpermanent

Comment: One comment i can give is, instead of that `switch` statement, you can optimize it by adding an empty array to local storage (if there is no key with name "note") when page is loaded. By this way, you can avoid the switch statement.

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu I personally like the suggestion I marked as the answer but i will look into your suggestion, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like when you save the first item into the localStorage (when there is nothing there), you are just saving it as an object. Then when you add the next item, you wrap it in an array.

Instead you could save the original object wrapped in an array, and then just push onto that one:

```
case null:
  localStorage.setItem("note", JSON.stringify([input]));
  break;
```

--

```
default:
    var note_array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("note"));
    console.log(note_array);

    note_array.push(input);

    localStorage.setItem("note", JSON.stringify(note_array));
    break;
```

See this [forked codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aObEdx)